# How to pass another function or instance to the celery task?

Tags: python, redis, celery, celery-task

I have created a celery task as below

```py
import os
import time

from celery import Celery
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL")
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND")


@celery.task(name="create_task")
def message_sender(sender_func, numbers: list, message: str):
    sender_func(numbers, message)
    return "Sent Successful"
```

And calling the task as below

```py
modem_conn = Modem()
task = message_sender.apply_async(
        kwargs={
            "sender_func": modem_conn.sms,
            "numbers": ["00000000"],
            "message": "sms sent",
        }
    )
```

But I am getting bellow error

```
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable
```

But if I call the task without `delay` or `apply_async`, then it workes. What could be the problem here and how can I achive this.

All I want to do is pass a function or instance while calling the celery task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The celery task is run in another instance than your app, and both instances communicate via the broker. Since you don't "call" the task function, but only send messages with serialized data that tell the worker which function to call, you can't send objects or functions. This is similar to multiprocessing, where only serialized text messages can be sent between the processes.

My approach would be to make the function known to the worker and then send e.g. a string with the name of the function and call it.

sender:

```
task = message_sender.apply_async(
    kwargs={
        "sender_func": "sms",
        "numbers": ["00000000"],
        "message": "sms sent",
    }
)
```

worker:

```
@celery.task(name="create_task")
def message_sender(sender_func, numbers: list, message: str):
    modem_conn = Modem()
    if sender_func == "sms":
        modem_conn.sms(numbers, message)
    return "Sent Successful"
```

You could also use [getattr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071/4396362) or [locals()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834451/4396362)

Comment: Although this does not solve the problem I was facing. Your explaination answer my question.

Comment: So what is your problem then?